# Voyager in Laravel project can't find CSS on a live server

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Currently I'm working on a Laravel project where I use Voyager for the back-end. 
Everything was working well until I moved it towards the live server.

Now when I go to example.net/admin I get a page without styling.

[Voyager admin page without css...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkEGK.png)

The front-end works normally as I wanted it to be.
I assume this is a path issue yet I have no idea how and where to fix this..

The weird thing is that it worked yesterday night, everything worked normal but today, when I tried to login, it seemed like it didn't load in the .css file...

My folder structure looks like:

```
domains
  |- example.net
  | |- app
  | |- awstats
  | |- bootstrap
  | |- config
  | |- database
  | |- hooks
  | |- logs
  | |- private_html
  | |- public_ftp
  | |- public_html
  | |- resources
  | |- routes
  | |- storage
  | |- tests
  | |- vendor
  |- .env
  |- [all the other files on here]
```

When I try to open the Voyager image on my browser, it shows me this path:

```
https://example.net/admin/voyager-assets?path=images%2Flogo-icon-light.png
```

The voyager.php in the /vendor/tcg/voyager/routes/ map shows me

```
    //Asset Routes
    Route::get('voyager-assets', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix.'VoyagerController@assets', 'as' => 'voyager_assets']);
```

But I'm not sure if this is related to this issue...

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong so I can fix this?

Thank you in advance